# WSO2 dataservice archive export (.car) throws following "error occurred while exporting the archive: index: 0, size: 0"

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-integration-studio

I am working on the Retail Banking Example which comes with the new WSO2 Developer Studio.

I am using Java 1.7 sdk with the developer studio

I have finished all the artifacts in the example and when i try to export the files as a carbon application archive (car) to be deployed on the server i get he following error.

"error occurred while exporting the archive: index: 0, size: 0"
see link below for error snapshot

This only happens when i try to export the Customer data service.
All the others i can export fine.

Am i missing something here ?
Any help on this would be appreciated

Umar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening due to a bug in the Data Service Exporter of Developer Studio 2.0.0 and it affects only Windows users.

This bug is fixed in the upcoming Developer Studio 2.0.1 release and you can download the final RC pack from [here](http://builder1.us1.wso2.org/~developerstudio/developer-studio/2.0.1/).

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana

Comment: Hi Harshana, I have downlaoded Developer Studio 2.0.1, but when updating through eclipse.. get the following error.                                                                                                                                    An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Comparison method violates its general contract!
Comparison method violates its general contract!       any idea ?

Comment: bye the way i have created a dataservice on the data server itself instead of creating an archive, i just wanted to solve this issue of creating archives seamlessly.

Comment: Hi Umar, You need to install the Developer Studio 2.0.1 on a fresh eclipse rather than updating the 2.0.0 installed one.